# How to handle a IOException by starting a new Activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, ioexception

I am trying to start my main page activity when an exception is thrown. Right now when the exception happens, the app shuts down and starts from the main page. I want for it to seamlessly go to the main page app, not give the user a waring that the app is shutting down. The error it gives me is this:

```
D/Issue with Http:: IOException
04-19 13:57:31.518 27520-27570/myapp W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: my webpage
04-19 13:57:31.518 27520-27570/myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
04-19 13:57:31.518 27520-27570/myapp W/System.err:     at myapp.HttpManager.MyHttpGet.httpDownloadData(MyHttpGet.java:79)
04-19 13:57:31.518 27520-27570/myapp W/System.err:     at myapp.HttpManager.MyHttpGet.doInBackground(MyHttpGet.java:53)
04-19 13:57:31.518 27520-27570/myapp W/System.err:     at myapp.HttpManager.MyHttpGet.doInBackground(MyHttpGet.java:31)
04-19 13:57:31.518 27520-27570/myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
04-19 13:57:31.518 27520-27570/myapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-19 13:57:31.519 27520-27570/myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
04-19 13:57:31.519 27520-27570/myapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
04-19 13:57:31.519 27520-27570/myapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
04-19 13:57:31.519 27520-27570/myapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-19 13:57:31.538 27520-27520/myapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-19 13:57:31.594 27520-27520/myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: myapp, PID: 27520
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at myapp.JSON.LoginJsonParser.checkUsername(LoginJsonParser.java:41)
at myapp.LoginPage$2.onClick(LoginPage.java:128)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is fine and dandy for dev, but I want to start a new activity when this happens. What I have code wise for this problem is this.

```
 private String httpDownloadData(String myUrl)

{
    String respone = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        //put in the username and pssword for parmas to send to url
        //this is good for login
        if (username!=null)
        {
            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
                }
            });
        }

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        if(inputStream != null)
        {
            respone = streamToString(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
        }

    }catch (IOException ie)
    {
        //ie.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Issue with Http: " , "IOException");
        ie.printStackTrace();
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), ECom.class);
        activity.startActivity(newIntent);
    }finally {
        if(urlConnection != null)
        {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return respone;
}
```

Thank you for any help with this.

Comment: According to your log details, your app throws more than IOException. Have you tried catching Exception in place of IOException in your catch block?

Comment: either use catch for `NullPointerException` too or use `Exception`

Comment: @VivekMishra good point I was thinking of just trying to stop it before it gets to my jsonparser, but then I realised my json parser can start an activity up so it works fine now thank you

Comment: You are using .contains somewhere in your code. Please post that code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform any networking operation in UI thread, it will give you networkOnMainThreadException. Please use AsyncTask to perform network and long running operation. You can find [samples and docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

or use [volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) a framework to handle network operations

Comment: good point and its on a async task that is dedicated to just doing downloading data from my server.

Answer (score 1):

You are handling only IOException in catch there can be a case where it will throw other exceptions in that case it will crash .as i can see in Log for NPE also so better is make sure what else exception your code can through or else use base Exception class which will take care all exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You must be perform the netWorking operation in the new thread,or use the framework,such as Volley,Okhhttp.Retrofit is the best framework now I use,it contains Okhttp and AsyncTask,but you may want to unite the RxJava.